# How to concatenate two arrays in R

Tags: r, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays.

Using `numpy.append` we can merge two arrays.

How can we do same thing in R?

`merge` can not do that.

Python Output/Example:

```
   a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,5])
   b=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
   np.append(a,b)

   array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])   # this is what I want
```

`x<-c(mat , (0.0) * (l - length(demeaned)))`

`mat is matrix (size is 20)`

`l - length(demeaned)` is 10

i want at the end 30 size

Comment: With the command `c(a, b)`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot  Done Thanks

Comment: @VincentGuillemot thanks

Answer (score 8):

The [`c`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/c)-function concatenates its arguments. A vector can be a concatenation of numbers or of other verctors:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,5)
b = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
c(a,b)

 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

At least for one-dimensional arrays like in your python-example this is equivalent to [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the previous answer, you can use `rbind` or `cbind` to create two-dimensional arrays (matrices) from simple arrays (vectors):

```
cbind(a,b)

# output
 a b
[1,] 1 0
[2,] 2 0
[3,] 3 0
[4,] 4 0
[5,] 5 0
[6,] 5 0
```

or

```
rbind(a,b)

# output
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
a    1    2    3    4    5    5
b    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

If you want to convert it back to vector, use `as.vector`. This

```
as.vector(rbind(a,b))
```

will give you a joined vector with alternating elements.

Also, note that `c` can flatten lists if you use the `recursive=TRUE` argument:

```
a <- list(1,list(1,2,list(3,4)))
b <- 10
c(a,b, recursive = TRUE)

# output
[1]  1  1  2  3  4 10
```

Finally, you can use `rep` to generate sequences of repeating numbers:

```
rep(0,10)
```

Comment: use `c(a,b,rep(0, l - length(demeaned)))`. I modified my post above

Comment: mat and  demeaned are same , i forgot to change it's name , syntax will remain the same ??

Comment: if `mat` is an array, then the syntax is `c(mat,rep(0, l - length(mat)))`